# Waiting for an AFHTTPRequestOperation to complete before continuing

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, nsoperation

i'm trying to make an iOS App that communicates with an API using `AFHTTPClient`. The first step is to authentificate the user, to do so, i use this code:

```
-(void)authorize
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"login.php" parameters:@{@"login": account.username, @"passwd":account.password}];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Token" value:[[operation.response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"CSRF-Token"]];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    [httpClient.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

As you can see, my code gets a token from the server response and sets it as a default header for all future requests.

I then proceed to other requests using `- (void)postPath:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:success failure:failure`

But when i used the debugger, i found out that those other requests where executed before the authorize operation was completed, therefore they failed because they didn't have the auth token. I added `[httpClient.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];` but it doesn't seem to work...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't use `wait` until anything functions. Those block app until the network connection finishes. Just put the necessary code in your `success` block and call `displayNextView` after it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [dispatch semaphore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

```
-(void)authorize
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t done = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"login.php" parameters:@{@"login": account.username, @"passwd":account.password}];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Token" value:[[operation.response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"CSRF-Token"]];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(done);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    [httpClient.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(done, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Note that this will block the method from returning, so you need to make sure it's not on the main/UI thread.

Comment: What do you mean by blocking the method from returning ?

Comment: I tried using it like this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
  
  [api authorize];
 });
 [api requestMethod:@"users"];`
But it still doesn't work, the requestMethod is called before

Comment: You have to make the subsequent requests in the same thread (or blocked by a lock/semaphore: `^{[api authorize]; [api doOtherRequests];}`. If needed, you could create a queue and just queue up methods until the authorize call is done.

Comment: Ok but when will the semaphore be notified that my operation is complete ?

Comment: The semaphore is notified by the signal (`dispatch_semaphore_signal`).